# Relationship between the generators of two different cyclic and totally ramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $L/K$ be a cyclic and totally ramified extension of degree $n$, generated by an element $\alpha$ (i.e. $L=K(\alpha)$). Let $L'/K$ be another cyclic and totally ramified extension of degree $n$ with $L \neq L'$. Consider the unramified extension $F/K$ of degree $n$ and embed $L,L',F$ in a common field $E$ (for instance, $E = \bar{K}$, an algebraic closure of $K$, or $E = LL' F$, the compositum of $L,L',F$).

> **Question**: Does there exist an element $c \in F^* \subseteq E^*$ such that $L'/K$ is generated by $c \alpha$ (i.e. $L'=K(c \alpha)$)?

I tried to consider the example $L' = (LF)^{\langle \sigma \tau \rangle}$ where $\sigma$ is a generator of $\operatorname{Gal}(LF/L)$, i.e. $L = (LF)^{\langle \sigma \rangle}$, and $\tau$ is a generator of $\operatorname{Gal}(LF/F)$, i.e. $F = (LF)^{\langle \tau \rangle}$. By definition, $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha$. If $\beta$ is a generator of $F/K$, then $\tau(\beta) = \beta$.

Now it would be interesting to see if one could describe an element $c \in F$ in terms of $\beta$ such that $(\sigma \tau)( c \alpha) = c \alpha$, and I expect this element to be a generator of $L'/K$. 
If we have Kummer extensions, i.e. $K$ contains a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta_n$, and $\tau(\alpha) = \zeta_n \alpha$ and $\sigma(c) = \zeta_n^{-1} c$ for an appropriate generator $c$ of $F/K$ (explicitly: $c,\dots,c^{n-1} \not\in K$ and $c^n \in K$), then $(\sigma \tau)(c \alpha) = c \alpha$ indeed.

But I have trouble showing the existence of such an element $c$ for the general case.

Could you please help me with my question and my approach?

Comment: Have you looked at examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: @Lubin: Yes, but only in the Kummer theoretic setting so far. I am unsure how to generalize this concept to non-Kummer fields. Still working on it though.

Comment: What about the case $p=2$, $L=\Bbb Q_2(i)$, $L'=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt2\,)$?

Comment: I checked that for $K=\mathbb{Q}_2$, both $L/K$ and $L'/K$ are totally ramified of degree $2$. First I considered $c = \sqrt{2}/i$ (so $L'=(ci)$) but $c$ has valuation $1/2$, so it is not in $F$. But maybe it would work if $i$ is replaced with a uniformizer of $L$. But I am not sure if this will lead me to the right direction. Was that your intention?

Comment: That was the only exception to your conjecture that I could think of. Tame ramification confuses me, but in this wild case, it seems to have to do with the fact that $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ is not topologically generated by a single element. Use other bases than $\Bbb Q_p$ and I imagine that one could find lots of counterexamples to any generalization of your suspicion.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the example you gave is indeed a counterexample?

Comment: I interpreted (perhaps misinterpreted) your conjecture as saying that $LL'$ would not be totally ramified over $\Bbb Q_p$, i.e. that $LL'$ would have residue field extension degree $f$ greater than $1$. In yet other words, that there would be an element of $F^*$ in $LL'$.

Comment: Maybe my wording was not optimal. I meant to ask that if  $L/K$ is a given cyclic and totally ramified extensions $L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $L'/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is another given cyclic and totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, can one always choose a generator of $L'/K$ to be $c \alpha$ for some constant $c \in F^*$ (i.e. the generators of $L/K$ and $L'/K$ are the same up to a constant).

Comment: For instance, the quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (for $p \neq 2$) are given by $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{u}) , \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{up})$ where $u$ is a non-square in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. The last two fields are exactly the quadratic totally ramified fields of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and only differ by $\sqrt{u}$ which generates the unramified quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Also, here I found a similar observation for cubic extensions: https://www.lmfdb.org/LocalNumberField/?n=3&e=3&gal=C3&search_type=List

I am now asking if there is a general pattern here.

Comment: And my last comment stands.